# Add thousands separator for view count

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, views

Question view counts can be hard to read when over 1,000. For example:

- "viewed 10000 times" would be clearer as "viewed 10,000 times":

[image: "viewed 10000 times"]

- "viewed 298513 times" would be clearer as "viewed 298,513 times":

[image: "viewed 298513 times"]

---

- Thousands separators are used elsewhere, for reputation:

[image: rep bar]

[image: profile reputation]

[image: next to a question]

- For question counts:

[image: total questions asked]